# Derivative for x-direction for image

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-analysis

I want to ask, consider we want to compute the slope of x-direction of the following step

[image].

The slope for it would be

$m =\frac{0}{m_2 - m_1} =\frac{0}{5 - 2}$ which is 0.

But the derivate for image in x-direction computed with (something like, some symbols aren't existed in my phone so lets just say $\frac{df}{dx}$)

$\frac{df}{dx} = f(x+1) - f(x)$

[image]

It's computed under the consideration of next pixel $f(x+1)$ minus current pixel $f(x)$.

Is there any interpretation that I'm missing, shouldn't it be 0, in both cases?

Comment: Unclear! are you telling some parallel shouldn't have slope zero? whats are you telling about image derivative. please give more info

Comment: @AlwynMathew when you improve the post and there are huge images, or small tables as images, it would be nice to also hack them.

Comment: @Evil actually I have no idea what those images means thus I don't want to confuse others who are looking at this question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, hi , it's actually `y2-y1/x2-x1`, I wrote it as simply `0/x2-x1`.Thanks everyone i was so confused about all this derivative.

Comment: @AlwynMathew I understand, me neither. As you have pointed out 9h ago it is unclear, so the OP should explain and improve the question (also images should be more readable or illustrate better instead of being confusing) and until it is clearer we could wait to improve it at once or let OP improve it.

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup please edit your question to include clarifications, do not post them as the comments. I do not understand the images (possibly not only me), morover these are quite huge in contrast to what they present. Could you use some vector editor?

Comment: Hi thanks yes It should have been better, btw if I didn't draw like i was afraid people get even confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you are asking about computing the derivative, at some pixel $(x,y)$, with respect to the $x$ direction. We can approximate a derivative of some function $f(x,y)$ along the $x$ direction using the following Finite Difference formula:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \approx \frac{f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)}{h} $$

for some $h \neq 0$, usually using $h \ll 1$ if possible. For an image, the best you can do with this formula is the following:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \approx \frac{f(x+1,y) - f(x,y)}{1} = f(x+1,y) - f(x,y) $$

This is because $f(x,y)$, the pixel color values at $(x,y)$, is a value of $1$ away from the nearest neighboring pixels in both the $x$ and $y$ direction.